# Reset of root password not working?

Tags: mysql, linux, password, password-recovery

Our previous DBA left and didn't note the root password down, and I've been pressganged into doing part of his job until we can hire someone.

So I create a file :

/root/mysql.password

Inside that file, I have:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpassword') WHERE User='root';
```

So I do a clean shutdown of the database, and then:

```
mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/mysql.password
```

I get 'starting mysqld' ... and then it exits with code 1.

I don't get it.  What's wrong with that file?

Using ..

```
mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

.. isn't an option, unfortunately, as it's a public-facing production box.

Thanks.

Comment: Or wait... is it because the init file has to have more than just an UPDATE in it, since I'm in effect telling the database to bypass /etc/my.cnf?

Comment: Have you seen this (the Unix paragraphs)? [How to Reset the Root Password](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 1):

The very first thing you should do is take a backup of your database using mysqldump or similar, because if you mangle something, your root password will be useless anyway.

Comment: Yes, it's a VM so I cloned it before touching it.  Yes, I've seen the MySQL doc, and was in fact working from that.

Answer (score 1):

**Different methods to reset 'root' password**

1)

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

2)

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('cleartext password');
```

3)

```
mysqladmin -u root password 'NEWPASSWORD'
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have been permissions

You had to run

```
chown mysql:mysql /root/mysql.password
```

or

```
chmod 777 /root/mysql.password
```

before starting mysqld